# Linux - create user through PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, permissions

I'm writing a PHP program that calls bash scripts. I'm using Linux (Centos). I'm trying to create a new user in Linux by entering username and password in the PHP page. this is the script I'm using:

```
egrep "^$1" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1 exists!"
    exit 1
else

    sudo useradd -m -p $2 $1
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
fi
```

this is how I call the script from PHP:

```
echo exec("/var/www/html/addUser.sh ".$username." ".$password);
```

it works when running it from terminal, but when calling the script from PHP it doesn't work. it is a matter of permissions. what should I do in order to allow the PHP (apache) to also add users?
I've tried adding 'apache' to visudo both as user and as a group:

```
%apache ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
 apache    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

it still doesn't work.
any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Holycow, remove that entry from /etc/sudoers. You're essentially granting Apache full access to your system.

Comment: still didn't get it to work. any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: While this is an old post, `%apache ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL` borders on criminally insane.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to let PHP run arbitary code on a web server *as root* -- this is extremely inadvisable, as if someone were to find a hole in your code and inject their own, they would literally be able to do anything they liked with your server!

That being said, you can call an external script using `exec("command");` or use backticks like:

```
$command_output = `shell_command`;
```

For more information see [php's exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

If you really do want to proceed with this, I would suggest storing your script (the one at the top that you'd like to run) and then calling that script with `exec()`, while only allowing sudo passwordless access to that one script.

**Additional:**

You might want to try [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of exec - this runs your command *in a shell*, which I think might fix any environment issues you may be having.

Comment: thanks. i've just tried the full permissions to PHP to see if it works. and it didn't. about 'exec' - I'm already using it to call the script. the question was how to allow PHP to create a new user.

Comment: Check what environment `exec()` is passing on to your script - might be that it is either failing to find your script or failing to set sudo up properly due to missing "presumed" environment variables. I have called useradd from a PHP page using backticks before, so it is possible and I see no reason `exec()` would be any different -- as I said though, highly inadvisable - No bad reflection on you for wanting to do it anyway, but I have to keep reiterating in case someone comes across this post in 6 months time ;)

Comment: I've just had one of those "while walking away from my computer" thoughts -- have you tried using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)?

Comment: it'd be interesting to see what the full output of your *shell* script was when it runs - any chance you could amend your `echo exec("/var/www/html/addUser.sh ".$username." ".$password);` to use backticks (exec only reproduces the last line when called with one argument) and post any results in your question?

Comment: I get "Failed to add a user! "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84751/discussion-between-stej-and-user2880391).